# Cardinality of an Integer Subset

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N_0$ be the set of all non-negative integers, and $N_0^k$ be the set of all $k$-tuples with elements in $N_0$. For any $x\in N_0^k$, define the height of $x$ as $\operatorname{ht}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k x_i$. Let $$\sigma (h)=\lbrace x\in N_0^k \mid \operatorname{ht}(x)=h\rbrace.$$ Show that $|\sigma(h)|=\binom{h+k-1}{k-1}$.

Not sure how to approach this, have never studied this kind of mathematics. I'm not sure how to count the elements in $\sigma$. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part do you need assistance with? Do you understand the relation between $\operatorname{ht}$ and elements in $N_0^k$ and what the elements in $N_0^k$ look like? What about $\sigma$? What elements are in it? Or are you having trouble counting the number of elements in $\sigma(h)$?

Comment: @FrenzyLi I'm not sure how to count the elements in $\sigma$, I understand what the sets themselves contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the elements in the tuple is fixed.  This is like asking how many ways you can distribute $h$ identical objects into $k$ bins and empty bins are allowed.  This problem is equivalent to the typical [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) (see theorem 2): putting $k$ bars in between $h$ items and it is allowed to have zero items between bars.  There are exactly
$$
  \binom{h+k-1}{k-1}
$$
ways to do so.